# Can' install Anaconda 3 on Ubuntu 21

Tags: ubuntu, installation, anaconda

this is the terminal output i get:

```
> Preparing transaction: done
>     Executing transaction: | 
>         Installed package of scikit-learn can be accelerated using scikit-learn-intelex.
>         More details are available here: https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex
>         For example:
>             $ conda install scikit-learn-intelex
>             $ python -m sklearnex my_application.py
>     done
>     installation finished.
>     Do you wish the installer to initialize Anaconda3
>     by running conda init? [yes|no]
>     [no] >>> yes
>     ./Anaconda3-2021.11-Linux-x86_64.sh: 489: [[: not found
>     no change     /home/hamsterofdeath/.bashrc
>     No action taken.
>     If you'd prefer that conda's base environment not be activated on startup, 
>        set the auto_activate_base parameter to false: 
>     
>     conda config --set auto_activate_base false
>     
>     Thank you for installing Anaconda3!
>     
>     ./Anaconda3-2021.11-Linux-x86_64.sh: 516: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")
```

what's wrong here?

stackoverflow doesn't let me post this because it's mostly code. but i have nothing more to say. i'll try to remove useless logs.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the script must run from bash and the default script for your distribution is not bash.

Try `sudo bash ./Anaconda3-2021.11-Linux-x86_64.sh`